# Which is the strongest metal in the Star Wars Universe?

Tags: star-wars

I know Beskar is quite strong, but which is the strongest metal in the Star Wars Universe?

Comment: Whatever they make plot armour out of

Comment: What do you mean by "strength"? Tensile strength? Compressive strength? Shear modulus strength? Shape retention? Something else?

Comment: @Lexible - I think you may be overthinking this slightly

Comment: @Valorum I think the OP is underthinking it: "strength" for metals is not one thing.

Answer (score 2):

According to Legends sources, Beskar was the 'toughest metal known to science'.

> Beskar was the toughest metal known to science. Even lightsabers had
> trouble with it. There had been a time when every army in the galaxy
> wanted a supply.
>
> <sub><sup>[Legacy of the Force: Sacrifice](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Legacy_of_the_Force:_Sacrifice)</sup></sub>